# Complex Equation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I have this problem to solve in $C$

$$(1-i)z^5-i=0$$

**My solution**

$$z^5=\frac{-1+i}{2} = \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} $$

Now I need to find args.

$$|z|=r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

$$tan(args)=\frac{b}{a} \rightarrow tan(args)= \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{-1}{2}}=\frac{2}{-2}=1$$

Therefore args=45 or 135 $\rightarrow$ 135.

For some reason I don't get the same $args$ and $|z|$ as the answer in the book.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: $b$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{i}{2}$. $z = a + ib$. Then the tangent is $-1$.

Comment: You calculated $|z^5| = \sqrt{2}/2$, not $|z|$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You'r right edited.

Comment: $|z|=\sqrt[5]{|z^5|}=\sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}\neq\sqrt[2]{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}$

Comment: So $|z| = ^5\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}$?

Comment: Exactly. For some reason, my browser doesn't show that piece of LaTex properly. So in words - you've calculated the $2$nd root of the length instead of the $5$th root of the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$z^5=\frac i{1-i}=\frac  i2(1+i)=\frac1{\sqrt2}e^{i\frac\pi2} e^{i\frac\pi4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}e^{3i\frac\pi4}$$

Now notice that

$$z^n=R e^{i\theta}\iff z=\sqrt[n]R\exp\left(\frac{i\theta+2ik\pi}{n}\right),\quad k=0,\ldots,n-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$|z^5|=\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}=>|z|=2^{-\frac 52}$$ now you can use De Moivre's theorem to find the args.